# Slider content showing and then hiding

Tags: joomla-2.5, jquery

I'm having an issue on a website where all of the sliders (there are 4) are being shown before quickly disappearing.

The site URL is:

http://185.123.97.225/~smithsde/index.php

On investigation this appears to be jQuery or Mootools doing this, but I can't figure out where/why.

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is a few things:

- You're importing jQuery multiple times
- You're site is rather heavy with scripts

The main thing that I'd say could be causing the issue is the entire JS script for the slider is being completely obfuscated by `eval()`:

http://185.123.97.225/~smithsde/modules/mod_fpss/includes/js/jquery.fpss.js

Meaning is has to un-obfuscate it first before actually executing it.

---

**What can you do?**

- Ensure only 1 instance of jQuery is being imported
- Whichever extension is calling Mootools...banish it and find an alternative.
- Find an alternative to the slider extension you're using.

Comment: Hi Lodder, I've just sent you an email about this, if you're able to help please?

Comment: @RustyJoomla - will take a look now